# Finding a Piece with a Picture

Tags: part-identification

I have been trying to find this Lego Piece for a while now and I just can't seem to find it. I saw this Lego Warthog MOC on Youtube by hachiroku24 and wanted to build it, but I can't seem to identify the main part of the turret. The piece is the black one in the lower middle and I can't seem to find it anywhere. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Here's the video URL for a better look at the piece:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg2NBk0SaIY&t=1s

Comment: I skimmed through the video, that's a pretty awesome build!  Hope you find the part you need :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The piece is question appears to be part# 15071, via Bricklink:

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=123914#T=C